# SSH Tunnel in background

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have a process that expects an ssh tunnel connection to execute correctly and I have been using the following command:

```
ssh -L localhost:3306:127.0.0.1:3306 username@<mysql-machine-ip-address> -N &
```

I have ran this successfully for 8 months, recently our hosting provider had to make hardware changes to update our machine, and upgraded our machine with a new kernel for Ubuntu. It went from 4.8.3-x86_64-linode76 to 4.8.6-x86_64-linode78.

After a bunch of trouble shooting we've had to update the command to this:

```
ssh -L localhost:3306:127.0.0.1:3306 username@<mysql-machine-ip-address> -fN
```

When researching the ssh documentation the -f parameter

> Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.
>   This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or
>   passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.  This
>   implies -n.  The recommended way to start X11 programs at a
>   remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.

When researching the bash command for "&"

> Place a process into the background (see multitasking in "Intermediate Use Of >The UNIX Operating System").

Is there fundamentally any difference in these 2 commands?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, there is. `ssh &` runs `ssh` in the background from the very beginning. `ssh -f` starts `ssh` in the foreground, allowing it to prompt for passwords etc., and only afterwards `ssh` puts itself in the background just before executing the requested command.

Comment: do you have any clue as to why with the new server I would be forced to use the ssh -f rather than the ssh &.  In addition to that, it sounds as if ssh -f is a better approach, would you agree to that?

Comment: Maybe the new system has a newer (or just different) ssh client?